# Want to store To,From,Bounce,and mailstatus in sql database?

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

On my postfix relay server i want that postfix do not create /var/log/maillog file and directly store To, From,Bounce Address and mail status directely in sql server database.
How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postfix does not have this out of the box (there is no direct way), you will need to write a script that parses the logs and adds it to your database.

One option might be to use syslog-ng and pass your logs to a parser script that stores them in  a database.

Comment: thanx Lucas Kauffman

Comment: can u provide me the parser script

Comment: You will have to write it yourself I'm afraid, maybe you can find one somewhere. I don't have any script to parse postfix messages.